# Springboot & Kotlin khttp error - Java 11 to Java 17 migration: How to allow reflective classes for a Specific dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to migrate from Java 11 to Java 17. My app is written in Springboot and Kotlin.

I am using ***khttp*** dependency to make client call (3rd party calls). It works fine with Java 11 as reflections are not restricted in Java 11, but this is not the same case with Java 17. I am facing the below error when I am using **khttp.get()**:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7225790e
```

Initially I fixed the build issue by adding jvmArgument to maven-surefire & maven plugin dependecy in my pom.xml like below:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version><!-- Your version --></version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, I am still unable to use my khttp.get methods as the VM options are not being applied to it.

How do I allow reflections to make my khttp.get() calls not in my local but on the server

PS: running with Java commands is not what I am looking for.